# Disable "Permanently added <host> ..." warning on local LAN

Tags: ssh, openssh

I have the following in my ***`ssh_config`*** to connect to machines on my local LAN and machines in a VM:

```
Host 172.16.*.*
StrictHostKeyChecking no
UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
```

However, each time I connect it produces a warning:

```
$ ssh jdoe@172.16.4.11
Warning: Permanently added '172.16.4.11' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
Enter passphrase for key '/Users/jdoe/.ssh/id_ed25519':
```

I'm using OpenSSH 7.1. How do I disable the warning on each connection for the local LAN?

Answer (score 93):

Append the following to your SSH config file:

```
LogLevel ERROR
```

Or append `-o LogLevel=ERROR` to the ssh command itself.

Comment: The SSH config file on Debian is `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` (not `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` !)

Comment: A bit of a warning setting loglevel=error: You can lose valuable failure information by doing this, such as connection timeout messages.

Comment: @rubo77 how is this comment relevant to this answer?  I think the OP asked about user's config file (`~/.ssh/config`).

Comment: I don't remember, maybe someone edited an answer or deleted a comment? anyway, it is true and has an upvode flag already, so it helped someone ;)

Answer (score 20):

You should be able to do this by changing your ssh configuration from the default log-level of "info" to "error" (the next level up).

Refer to the [`ssh_config`](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man5/ssh_config.5?query=ssh_config) manual page:

> **`LogLevel`**
>   Gives the verbosity level that is used when logging messages from ssh(1). The possible values are: `QUIET`, `FATAL`, **`ERROR`**, **`INFO`**, `VERBOSE`, `DEBUG`, `DEBUG1`, `DEBUG2`, and `DEBUG3`. The default is **`INFO`**. `DEBUG` and `DEBUG1` are equivalent. `DEBUG2` and `DEBUG3` each specify higher levels of verbose output.

The source code for `ssh` tells the story:

```
    /*
     * Initialize "log" output.  Since we are the client all output
     * actually goes to stderr.
     */
    log_init(av[0], options.log_level == -1 ? SYSLOG_LEVEL_INFO : options.log_level,
        SYSLOG_FACILITY_USER, 1);
```

along with the definition of `log_init`:

```
void
log_init(char *av0, LogLevel level, SyslogFacility facility, int on_stderr)
{
```

i.e., all of the "log" messages go to the standard error, and you can only adjust how many you get.  The one you do not want happens to be at the **`INFO`** level.

Answer (score 7):

In short, run ssh with the -q flag to disable warnings/diagnostics (but not errors).

Comment: `-q` will do more than you probably bargained for. It suppresses very useful error messages. Example: `ssh -q not-existing-host` will not print a single error message. This command just fails silently. In contrast, `ssh -o LogLevel=error not-existing-host` will print an explanation: _ssh: Could not resolve hostname not-existing-host: Name or service not known_

Comment: I think using `grep -v` is better than suppressing all warnings or errors

Comment: Bad advice: -q will also hide "permission denied", which is fairly fundamental.

Answer (score 4):

Most answers here are not that perfect, where you will lose other important warning or error messages. To only suppress that warning message `'Permanently added ...'` and keep other warning messages, you could do the following:

Using error redirection and `grep -v`

The warning message that you've seen on the terminal is a `standard error`. So, we need convert the standard error output to standard output and finally using `grep -v` to remove that annoying warning string:

```
ssh jdoe@172.16.4.11 2> >(grep -v "Permanently added" 1>&2)
```

Even you could suppress the warning for only that specific IP:

```
ssh jdoe@172.16.4.11 2> >(grep -v "Permanently added '[172.16.4.11]'" 1>&2)
```

If you need to suppress more than one warning messages use `grep -Ev` and separate the warning messages with `|`:

```
 ssh jdoe@172.16.4.11 2> >(grep -v grep -Ev "Permanently added|Warning message 1|Other error message 2|Other error or warning N" 1>&2)
```

This way, you still able to view other important warning or error messages.

Answer (score 2):

if you used the command line

```
$ ssh xxx@xxx uname -m
Warning: Permanently added 'xxx' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.

Authorized users only. All activities may be monitored and reported.
aarch64
```

add option `-E /dev/null -o LogLevel=error`

```
$ ssh -E /dev/null -o LogLevel=error xxx@xxx uname -m
aarch64
```